# return max of a key in an embedded document on mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

given the example document

```
{
  "user_id": "user 1",
  "log":[
     {
        "index" : 1,
        "position" : 50
     },
     {
        "index" : 2,
        "position" : 70
     },
     {
        "index" : 3,
        "position" : 60
     }
   ]
},
{
  "user_id": "user 2",
  "log":[
     {
        "index" : 1,
        "position" : 150
     },
     {
        "index" : 2,
        "position" : 570
     },
     {
        "index" : 3,
        "position" : 60
     }
   ]
},
```

how can I return the **user_id** with the highest **position** and it's respective **index** on the mongo own shell?
In this case, the result will be:

1. user_id="user 2"
2. position = 570
3. index = 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/) the `log` array of each doc and then [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/) the resulting docs by `position`:

```
db.test.aggregate({$unwind: '$log'}, {$sort: {'log.position': -1}}, {$limit: 1})
```

Comment: Note that you need to be using Mongo 2.1 or newer to be able to use the aggregation framework.

Comment: Thanks, it works... at least with not so many data. I treid with my 600 MB db, and my computer totally crashed....